# Is the question asking for the burial practices followed when a Muslim dies too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

The question https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10217/3487 appear to be too broad for the Q&A model plus it appear to be a question that can be answered using commonly-available resources.

Share your analysis.

Should it be closed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I would call it "too broad"; if nothing else, the [existing answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10220/22) clearly shows that it *can* be answered concisely (not that I can vouch for its accuracy).

It's not a good question by any means, as it shows zero effort (and, as you say, it appears to be something that's probably easy enough to find otherwise), but that's something that can be easily handled by downvoting.  Closing seems unnecessary in this case.